# cassandra update table from java code

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, materialized-views

I am trying to implement various partitioning in Cassandra for a table. My basic idea is to assign every row some disk number and then put those in various views as per their disk number. For RoundRobin partitoning here is what I'm doing :

```
System.out.println("\n\nRR PARTITIONING\n\n");
    results = session.execute("select * from user;");
    int i=0, disk_no=0, total_disks=4;
    for(Row row: results)
    {
        String emailid = row.getString("email");
        disk_no = i++%total_disks;
        session.execute("update user set disk_no="+disk_no+" where email="+emailid+";");

        System.out.println("Disk "+disk_no+ ": "+ row.getString("firstname")+" "+row.getString("lastname")+" "+ row.getInt("age"));
    }
    session.execute("create materialized view RRDisk0 as select * from user where disk_no =0 and email is not null;");
    session.execute("create materialized view RRDisk1 as select * from user where disk_no =1 and email is not null;");
    session.execute("create materialized view RRDisk2 as select * from user where disk_no =2 and email is not null;");
    session.execute("create materialized view RRDisk3 as select * from user where disk_no =3 and email is not null;");
```

The error I'm facing which says :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:44 no viable alternative at character '@'
```

Please help me, I've been working on this since two hours and can't pinpoint what's wrong.

Comment: `"update user set disk_no="+disk_no+" where email='"+emailid+"';"`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to **quote** *`emailid`* value in update query. This should be:

```
`session.execute("update user set disk_no="+disk_no+" where email='"+emailid+"';");`
```